# Update user with devise polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, polymorphic-associations

I experiencing an issue on the update of a polymorphic association.
Actually, I've several type of users such as `Admin`, `Customer`, etc...
But on the update of a customer (for example), it fails because devise ask for a password.

I've the `User` model which only have devise logic:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise  :database_authenticatable,
          :registerable,
          :recoverable,
          :rememberable,
          :trackable,
          :validatable

  belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true
end
```

**customer.rb:**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :role, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And on the controller side, **customers_controller.rb:**

```
def update
  if @customer.update customer_params
    redirect_to dashboard_path, flash: { success: t('validation.update', model: @customer.class.model_name.human.downcase) }
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private

def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:firstname, :lastname, user_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
end
```

Here is my form view:

```
= simple_form_for @customer do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.fields_for :user do |u|
      = u.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true
      = u.input :password, autocomplete: 'off', hint: t('devise.registrations.edit.leave_blank_if_you_don_t_want_to_change_it'), required: false
      = u.input :password_confirmation, required: false
      = u.input :current_password, hint: t('devise.registrations.edit.we_need_your_current_password_to_confirm_your_changes'), required: true

    = f.input :firstname
    = f.input :lastname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in the form you have added `required: false` for `password` and `password_confirmation` field.

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, it
>   specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the
>   form.

BUT that is not going to restrict Devise from asking for password. By default, in Devise its mandatory which will performed every time you update a record.

If you want to update the record without providing password then follow the guidelines mentioned in Devise **[How To: Allow users to edit their account without providing a password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)**